# Image is not retrieve using url

Tags: .htaccess

I have an android app where i want to **display image** which i have uploaded in server.But i am not able to do so ,as my server side have **.htaccess file** where i am redirecting all my method request to .php page . and the folder where the image is save is also there in that folder , where **.htaccess file exists** .

In my android app i am displaying image using Picasso library ,so whenever i put  url of image it gives me error like access denied or file not found . but,images are present in upload_folder.

**This is my .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.+$ sample.php [L]
```

**This my server-side directory structure :**

```
- root
 - upload_folder
   - img1.jpg
   - img2.jpg
 - .htaccess
 - myphpfile.php
```

Also i am accessing my .php page in this way

http://example.com/root/getall_rentalpackages/?apiKey=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInXVC

So whenever i request for image like below it doesn't retrieve image.

http://example.com/root/upload_folder/img1.jpg

How can i display image using url and what changes i need to make in .htaccess file whenever image request is there ? I don't know much about .htaccess please help me .Thank you

Comment: Have you ever tried in desktop and call the same image url? If it's returns the same error, then consider editing your `.htaccess` file to `RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sample.php?/$1 [L]
`

Comment: I tried it ,still didn’t work :(

Comment: I guess it has a permission issue of directory

Comment: @ParthPatel yes ,because there is `.htaccess` in that folder , can you help me with this what changes need to be make in `.htaccess` file?

Comment: For that, you have to give permission to your directory. If you are working on Linux kind of Platform then visit https://askubuntu.com/questions/158735/how-to-set-permissions-so-that-i-can-read-and-write-to-another-partition

Comment: @ParthPatel no the folder which i am accessing using url is hosted online .

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?  Just curious.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman No , still didn't got i tried different way but `.htaccess`  was giving problem so if you have any solution please feel free to answer :) .

Comment: @Swati Yes, I am having the same issue, just stumbled upon this and thought of asking... Alright, I'll have a look through and let you know if I find an answer, I'll answer here...  Thanks again.